# Magento geo-location and multiple warehouses.

Tags: magento, geolocation, multiple-databases

This is a complex issue. So if you like to work on tough problems then this situation is for you. I'm running a Magento store that sells tires. I get tires from multiple warehouses. Some warehouses have unique tires but many of the warehouses carry the same tire that other warehouses have but, they are sold to me at different prices.

All warehouses will deliver my tires to the customer locally and all warehouses will UPS ship my tires anywhere.

Here is the problem. While a customer is shopping they select their tire. The results could have several of the same tire from many warehouses. They need to be able to pick  the one that is from their local warehouse so that warehouse can deliver with their trucks.

But, if there is no tire from the local warehouse then the customer will be okay with UPS. Since tires are expensive to ship, the tire needs to come from the closest warehouse for UPS delivery.

I am trying to come up with the best way to set up the catalog and tie it into this unique shipping situation. Shopping by Geo-location and multi warehouses. I would lobe to have each warehouse in their own database. If not then I'll use a prefix on each sku.  Any ideas? Thanks in advance. JJB

Answer (score 0):

### Shopping by Geo-location and multi warehouses.

1a You should [setup](http://www.crucialwebhost.com/blog/how-to-setup-multiple-magento-stores/) the multiple websites. Multiple websites allow you multiple items to have different stock.

1b Also you may buy some of the modules which allow your items to have multiple stock.

2 I don't know if you need it, but there are such solutions like mod_geoip for Apache.

Comment: Jevgeni thanks for the input and the Apache module suggestion. I don't think the the multi site is going to work. I need the customers to be on the same site and I still need to be able to cross over the inv. between stores/sites for the UPS shipping. I didn't look into multiple stock modules. I was focused on the geolocation aspect.

Comment: Well, mainly multi-warehouse is achieved only with 2 options: custom module, multi-website.

Answer (score 0):

I found [Multi-Warehouse](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/multi-warehouse.html) custom module in Magento connect that might be a solution.

Comment: Piwas thanks for the lead on the multi warehouse. I was too focused on the location. This may the solution. But it is a bit $$$ to try and see.